# Ambiguous method call

Tags: java, java-8

The below code block

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            log("1234", "main", "try");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("main", "Error in main",e);
        }

    }

    static void log(String methodName, Object message, Throwable t) {
        LOGGER.error("[Method Name :" + methodName + "] [Message :" + message + "]", t);
    }

    static void log(String requestId, String method, Object message) {
        LOGGER.error("[RequestId :" + requestId + "]" + "[Method Name :" + method + "] [Message :" + message + "]");
    }
}
```

gives an error for the method call in the `catch` block stating

> error: reference to log is ambiguous
>               log("main", "Error in main",e);
>               ^
>     both method log(String,Object,Throwable) in Test and method log(String,String,Object) in Test match

I'm not able to understand it. I went through lot of questions here but most of them either have varargs or generics involved. Couldn't determine what's wrong with the above code though.
Going through the JSL unable to determine what rule am I violating. Any help in understanding this would be great.

I know some questions talked about

- Renaming the methods
- Explicit type-casting for parameters

as solutions to make it clear for the compiler which method to pickup. But I'm looking forward to understand why the overloaded methods don't work here. Also if type-casted the second parameter to `Object` the code works fine, But why?

Some question did refer to type inference improved in Java 8 than 7, so to clarify I'm running this on Java 8.

Comment: Since String and Throwable inherits from Object the compiler can't determine which method to use since both matches. Why make `message` an object? I think you should remove any use of `Object` as parameter type and use concrete types instead, it will make it clearer and easier to understand how to use the methods and the compiler will be happy

Comment: Not an answer to question, but slf4j does not suffer from problems like this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have added the code just as the demo to convey the idea. I'm writing a wrapper around the logger so that actual implementation can be hidden and some more params that I have to add can be logged as well. Generally for a logging bit I would prefer to have it declared as `Object` as it gives the flexibility to log anything or not having to explicitly call `toString` everytime

Comment: Almost everyone that sees a log method that takes an argument named `message` would expect that argument to be of type String so for me your solution is just confusing. If anything you should have a something like a `customObject`, `extraInfo` or similar of type Object that could complement the message parameter.

Comment: Yeah I get that but to start with current implementation I'm planning on using Log4J, which allows Object as parameter so was trying to keep it similar to that. I'm aware of Log4J parameters, but then was thinking of wrappers around `log(Object message)` to start with.

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't appear to be anything to do with generics.

You have a method call

```
log("main", "Error in main",e);
```

and the compiler doesn't know if you're trying to call

```
log(String, Object, Throwable)
```

or

```
log(String, String, Object)
```

since both would match and neither is more specific than the other.

To make it clear, you could cast:

```
log("main", (Object) "Error in main", e);
```

if you want the first, or

```
log("main", "Error in main", (Object) e);
```

if you want the second.

Or write a `log` method more precisely matching the arguments you intend to pass to it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two log methods and both of them would match the call `log("main", "Error in main",e);`

Because you pass the following arguments:

- "main" -> String
- "Error in main" -> String
- e -> Exception

now which of your log methods should be called?

Both methods would accept these arguments.

### log method 1

```java
static void log(String methodName, Object message, Throwable t)
```

- "main" -> `String` -> matches `String methodName`
- "Error in main" -> `String` is also an `Object` -> matches `Object message`
- e -> `Exception` -> `Exception` is a `Throwable` -> matches `Throwable t`

### log method 2

```java
static void log(String requestId, String method, Object message)
```

- "main" -> `String` -> matches `String requestId`
- "Error in main" -> `String` -> matches `String method`
- e -> `Exception` -> `Exception` is an `Object` -> matches `Object message`

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity is arising because the third parameter `Exception` is both a `Throwable` and an `Object`.  Use this version for the second logging method:

```
static void log(String requestId, String method, String message) {
    LOGGER.error("[RequestId :" + requestId + "]" + "[Method Name :" + method + "] [Message :" + message + "]");
}
```

Now the following two calls are not ambiguous:

```
log("1234", "main", "try");
log("main", "Error in main", e);
```

Comment: This would require explicit conversion of log message to String every time which is something I was trying to avoid. Also current implementation I'm planning on using Log4J, which allows Object as parameter so was trying to keep it similar to that.

Comment: @Hegdekar The other answers also seem to require explicit casting.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to understanding the working behind this. Roughly interpreter tries to find the exact matching method, if not it tries promotion to parent type. But is it like promoting done for all parameter and then matching method is found? or parameter type promotion is done for each and then matching method is found? For me it looks like first one is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The Error Msg states, that there are two Methods that could solve your request `log(String,Object,Throwable)` and `log(String,String,Object)`.
The Interpreter could either cast your `String` to `Object` and keep the `Exception` a `Throwable` or it could cast the `Throwable` to an `Object` and keep the `String` as it is. Both possibilities require one cast, so it throws the exception instead of guessing which variant you would prefer.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `log` with a `String`, a `String` and a `Throwable`, how would you solve the ambiguity? There is no preference regarding the order of arguments... So Java is both able to "promote" the String to Object and call the first one, or "promote" the Throwable to an Object and chose the second one, with no preference, thus the ambiguity.

If you enforce the type of the second argument to Object then of course the compiler will have no choice, it looks to a method whose signature begin with `(String,Object,` thus the first one.

Your problem is that you are overloading the function by contravariance, one parameter by generalizing the type, and another parameter by specializing the type. There is no solution. Prefer not doing it...

Answer (score 1):

When you call `log` with the argument types `(String,String,Throwable)`, both methods

```
static void log(String methodName, Object message, Throwable t)
static void log(String requestId, String method, Object message)
```

are applicable, but neither is more specific than the other. For the second argument, `String` is a more specific type than `Object`, but for the third, `Throwable` is more specific than `Object`.

You can solve this by adding another overload

```
static void log(String methodName, String message, Throwable t) {
  log(methodName, (Object)message, t);
}
```

as then, this new overload is more specific than the others and will be selected when invoking `log` with `(String,String,Throwable)`.

An alternative is to make the second method more versatile by changing it to

```
static void log(String requestId, String method, Object... message) {
  LOGGER.error("[RequestId :" + requestId + "]" + "[Method Name :" + method
    + "] [Message :" + (message.length == 1? message[0]: Arrays.toString(message)) + "]");
}
```

Now it accepts multiple message arguments, but will behave the same as before when being called with only one argument. Since varargs methods have less precedence when multiple methods are applicable, calling `log` with `(String,String,Throwable)` will select the first method which has `(String,Object,Throwable)` parameter types.